# Group by and filter on 2 distinct values on other column with 1 value mandatory

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table T1

```
Jn company
X1 c1
X1 c2
X1 c3
Y2 c1
Y2 c2
Y2 c3
Z3 c2
Z3 c3
Z3 c4
```

I want to group by Jn and filter only those records which have atleast 2 disintct companies and 1 of them should be c1.

Desired result:

```
X1
Y2
```

I was trying like this

```
select Jn from T1
group by Jn
having -----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Jn
from your_table
group by Jn
having count(distinct company) >= 2 
   and sum(case when company = 'c1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `count()`

```
    select Jn  from T1          
    group by jn
    having count(distinct company)>=2
    and sum(case when company='c1' then 1 else 0 end)>0
```

Comment: I want it where there are atleast 2 distinct companies and 1 of them should be c1. Forgot to add that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t1.Jn 
from table t1
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.jn = t1.jn and t2.company = 'c1')
```

EDIT :

```
select t1.Jn 
from table t1
group by jn
having count(distinct company) >= 2 and
       sum(case when company = 'c1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: I want it where there are atleast 2 distinct companies and 1 of them should be c1. Forgot to add that part.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with your test data.  I get all the Jns having at least 2 companies then intersect that with those having company C1

```
SELECT Jn
FROM T1
GROUP BY Jn
HAVING COUNT(Company) >= 2

INTERSECT

SELECT Jn
FROM T1
WHERE Company = 'c1'
GROUP BY Jn;
```